# Resgastar id da noticia que estou a clicar?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho um app móvel com uma zona onde listo varias noticias através do `ng-repeat`. Agora tenho um sistema de gosto (*like*) de cada noticia onde tem um botão para fazer gosto da noticia.

O que acontece agora é que tenho de pegar o `id` da noticia e já estou a conseguir, mas quando faço gosto numa noticia ele resgata o `id` de outra noticia e não a que eu cliquei.

**PHP**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Content-type: application/json");

require_once("../funcoes/funcoes.php");


$result_posts_home = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts_home WHERE activo = :activo ");
$result_posts_home->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result_posts_home->execute();
$posts_home = $result_posts_home->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($posts_home as $row_posts_home) {

    $result_posts_home_anexos = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts_home_anexos WHERE id_mae = :id_mae AND seccao = :seccao ");
    $result_posts_home_anexos->bindParam(':id_mae', $row_posts_home->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_posts_home_anexos->bindValue(':seccao', 'thumbnail', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result_posts_home_anexos->execute();
    $row_posts_home_anexos = $result_posts_home_anexos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // VALIDA SE USER JA TEM LIKE NO POST

    $total_likes = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id_post = :id_post AND user_id = :user_id ");
    $total_likes->bindValue(':id_post', $row_posts_home->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $total_likes->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $total_likes->execute();
    $likes = $total_likes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    $noticias[] = array(
        'id'         => $row_posts_home->id,
        'id_anexo'   => $row_posts_home_anexos->id_anexo,
        'tipo'       => $row_posts_home_anexos->tipo,
        'likes'      => $row_posts_home->likes,
        'url_artigo' => $row_posts_home->url_artigo,
    );

}

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->result = $noticias;
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ListaNoticiasHome', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, sessionService, $partilharRecursos) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_noticias_home.php").success(function (data) {
        $scope.noticias_home = data.result;

        angular.forEach(data.result, function(value, key){
           $partilharRecursos.set('idNoticia', value.id);
        });   
    });
})
```

**View**

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="noticias in noticias_home">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticias.id}}">
                <div style="background: url(https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/posts_home/{{noticias.id_anexo}}.{{noticias.tipo}}); border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px; height: 200px; background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div style="border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; height: 100px; background-color: white;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                            <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticias.id}}"><div style="font-size: 15px; color:black; margin:5px 0px 15px 10px;  font-weight: bold; ">{{noticias.titulo}}</div></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                           <div ng-init="liked='Gosto'" ng-click="like()" ng-controller="LikeNoticiasHome" style="margin-left:10px;" class="botao_gosto"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{liked}}</div>
                           <div id="mostra_gostos" class="mostra_gostos">{{noticias.likes}}</div>
                           <a onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('{{noticias.titulo}}', 'SabeOnde', 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/posts_home/{{noticias.id_anexo}}.{{noticias.tipo}}', 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/{{noticias.url_artigo}}')" href=""><div class="botao_posts"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Partilhar</div></a>
                           <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticias.id}}"><div class="botao_posts"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Ver +</div></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller Like**

```
.controller('LikeNoticiasHome', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, sessionService, $partilharRecursos) {
    var hasLiked = false;
    $scope.like= function (){

        if (!hasLiked) {
            hasLiked = true;
            $scope.liked = 'Não Gosto';
            $scope.likeCount += 1;

            $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_like_noticias.php?post_id="+$partilharRecursos.get("idNoticia")+ "&user_id=" + sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
                $scope.like_noticias_home = data;
            });

        } else {
            hasLiked = false;
            $scope.liked = 'Gosto';
            $scope.likeCount -= 1;

            $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_unlike_noticias.php?post_id="+$partilharRecursos.get("idNoticia")+ "&user_id=" + sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
                $scope.like_noticias_home = data;
            });
        }     
    }
})
```

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar a **view** do **controller** *ListaNoticiasHome*?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei lá

Comment: Você tem que passar a id da notícia no método de click e capturar no seu controller a referência no banco. É a mesma coisa quando você manda a rota via get... não tem como ser diferente disso.

Comment: Como capturo e isso que nao percebo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo, basta você passar a **id** para dentro do seu scope, e processar seu método para a mesma:

```
.controller('LikeNoticiasHome', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, sessionService, $partilharRecursos) {
    var hasLiked = false;
    $scope.like= function (id) {

      if (!hasLiked) {
         hasLiked = true;
         $scope.liked = 'Não Gosto';
         $scope.likeCount += 1;

         $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_like_noticias.php?post_id=" + id + "&user_id=" + sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
            $scope.like_noticias_home = data;
         });

      } else {
        hasLiked = false;
        $scope.liked = 'Gosto';
        $scope.likeCount -= 1;

        $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_unlike_noticias.php?post_id=" + id + "&user_id=" + sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
            $scope.like_noticias_home = data;
        });
      }  

    }
});
```

E na sua view:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="noticias in noticias_home">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticias.id}}">
                <div style="background: url(https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/posts_home/{{noticias.id_anexo}}.{{noticias.tipo}}); border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px; height: 200px; background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div style="border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; height: 100px; background-color: white;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                            <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticias.id}}"><div style="font-size: 15px; color:black; margin:5px 0px 15px 10px;  font-weight: bold; ">{{noticias.titulo}}</div></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                           <div ng-init="liked='Gosto'" ng-click="like({{noticias.id}})" ng-controller="LikeNoticiasHome" style="margin-left:10px;" class="botao_gosto"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{liked}}</div>
                           <div id="mostra_gostos" class="mostra_gostos">{{noticias.likes}}</div>
                           <a onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('{{noticias.titulo}}', 'SabeOnde', 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/posts_home/{{noticias.id_anexo}}.{{noticias.tipo}}', 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/{{noticias.url_artigo}}')" href=""><div class="botao_posts"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Partilhar</div></a>
                           <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticias.id}}"><div class="botao_posts"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Ver +</div></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Grande, teria a possibilidade de tu postar o código de tua função like() que está no controller que tu fez no angular, provavelmente o problema está nela, antes de tu postar ela aqui, tu pode tentar mudar ela, colocar ela  sem pegar o id da notícia pelo scope e sim passando ele como parâmetro na função e tratando ela de forma independente dentro da função like().

No caso com o like quando vc faz isso

```
$scope.like= function (id){
...//cod
}
```

Essa função ao ser chamada no view terá de receber um parâmetro, e no ng-click da sua view, mais precisamente na div onde você faz o controle do like, basta deichar assim,

```
ng-click="like(noticia.id)"
```

Assim você passa o ID da noticia clicada.

No caso também percebi que você está tratando o $scope.liked como uma variável geral, seria interessante não trabalhar com ela assim, pois se você informar um valor para ela, esse valor será utilizado em todo o scope, no caso para simplificar isso, você poderia utilizar a function like recebendo como parâmetro também uma variável noticia, por exemplo:

```
<div>... ng-click="like(noticia)"...


   .controller('LikeNoticiasHome', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, sessionService, $partilharRecursos) {
   // var hasLiked = false;
$scope.like= function (noticiaClicada){

    if (!noticia.hasLiked) {
        noticiaClicada.hasLiked = true;
        $scope.noticiaClicada.liked = 'Não Gosto';
        $scope.likeCount += 1;

        $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_like_noticias.php?post_id="+$partilharRecursos.get("idNoticia")+ "&user_id=" + sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
            $scope.like_noticias_home = data;
        });

    } else {
        noticiaClicada.hasLiked = false;
        $scope.noticiaClicada.liked = 'Gosto';
        $scope.likeCount -= 1;

        $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_unlike_noticias.php?post_id="+$partilharRecursos.get("idNoticia")+ "&user_id=" + sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
            $scope.like_noticias_home = data;
        });
    }     
}
})
```

Ok, no caso você pode tentar usar o ng-repeat direto no código de tua tabela.

```
<tr ng-repeat="noticia in noticias">
<td colspan="2" valign="top">
    <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticia.url_artigo}}/{{noticia.id}}"><div style="font-size: 15px; color:black; margin:5px 0px 15px 10px;  font-weight: bold; ">{{noticia.titulo}}</div></a>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                       <div ng-init="liked='Gosto'" ng-click="like(noticia.id)" ng-controller="LikeNoticiasHome" style="margin-left:10px;" class="botao_gosto"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{liked}}</div>
                       <div id="mostra_gostos" class="mostra_gostos">{{noticia.likes}}</div>
                       <a onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('{{noticia.titulo}}', 'SabeOnde', 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/posts_home/{{noticia.id_anexo}}.{{noticias.tipo}}', 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/{{noticia.url_artigo}}')" href=""><div class="botao_posts"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Partilhar</div></a>
                       <a href="#/app/ver-noticia/{{noticias.url_artigo}}/{{noticia.id}}"><div class="botao_posts"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Ver +</div></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Nesse caso que fiz acima, apenas peguei aquele array que você alimenta no foreach php e coloquei ele para alimentar variáveis na tabela, agora ele não deve mais pegar o id da notícia errada, mas nesse caso o foreach que usava no controller ListaNoticiasHome não será mais necessário ok.

Comment: Já coloquei o controller like como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: No caso editei a resposta por que não tinha visto que tu havia colocado o like do controller, desculpa grande, foi só um pouco de falta de atenção mesmo.

Comment: Continua a dar levar o id errado

Comment: E o resto de cima a imagem e todo como vao aparecer se mudar o ng-repeat para a tabela

Comment: Quando você faz o ng-repeat dentro da tabela, o angular se encarrega de repetir o código utilizando os valores do array jogando em variáveis independentes, replicando o código dentro da <table> sem prejudicar a execução do código.

Comment: Mas repete os botoes

Comment: repete sim, pq eles estão dentro do conteúdo da tabela.

Comment: Mas nao pode repeter

Comment: Nesse caso você pode tentar deixar os botôes fora do código da tabela, e no ng-click continua do jeito que está, mas o ruim é que deixando fora você terá que adicionar outro ng-click onde ele chama uma função recebendo um parâmetro como a que existe hoje que vai alimentar uma variável dentro do angular e após isso ela chama a função para gravar o like

Comment: O mais correto seria repetir o botão like para cadas notícia, deixaria o código mais legível e a usabilidade do sistema seria melhor por parte do usuário, assim ficaria melhor para você acompanhar cada like da notícia

Comment: Grande deu certo a implementação do código?

Answer (score 0):

Como você está chamando o **like()** dentro de um **ng-repeat**, recomendo que passe o **id** vindo do **ng-repeat** para a função **like()**. É comum ter esse tipo de problema, pois no laço de repetição o *angular* isola os escopos.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
angular.module("myApplication", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.notices = [];
    $scope.notices.push({id: 1, name: "AAA"});
    $scope.notices.push({id: 2, name: "BBB"});
    $scope.notices.push({id: 3, name: "CCC"});

    $scope.like = function(notice_id) {
      alert('Id da notícia: ' + notice_id);
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h2>POSTS</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="notice in notices">
        <td ng-bind="notice.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="notice.name"></td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="like(notice.id)">like</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pode dar o exemplo no meu controller que tenho como ficaria ?